# Python regex extra character on re.sub (Regex replacement)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a simple function to replace only accented characters with normal ones:

```
import re

def remove_accents(r):
    r = re.sub("[àáâãäå]", 'a', r)
    r = re.sub("[èéêë]", 'e', r)
    r = re.sub("[ìíîï]", 'i', r)
    r = re.sub("[òóôõö]", 'o', r)
    r = re.sub("[ùúûü]", 'u', r)
    r = re.sub("[ýÿ]", 'y', r)

    return r
```

The problem I'm having is the next one, when I try to replace the accented character with the normal one, Python is adding an extra character and I don't know why.

**Example**

```
import re

my_string = "Joaquín Noriega"
print re.sub(r"[ìíîï]", r'i', my_string)
```

This is what I get on my output:

```
Output: 'Joaquiin Noriega'
```

Note the double '**ii**' on the name, it should be '**Joaquin Noriega**'

- Why is this happening ? Is there something wrong with my regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 strings are bytes, so as UTF-8, the regex really looks like this:

```
'[\xc3\xac\xc3\xad\xc3\xae\xc3\xaf]'
```

`í` in `"Joaquín Noriega"` is encoded the same way – as two bytes – and they both match the character class, so they’re both replaced with the single-byte `i`.

The preferable fix to this is to switch to Python 3 (it has sane text handling), but if you can’t, Unicode strings will do:

```
import re

my_string = u"Joaquín Noriega"
print re.sub(u"[ìíîï]", u'i', my_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quick answer ! It works perfectly and most important, now I understand what was happening.